# reference and class namespace

Tags: .net

I am having trouble linking to a secondary class in my project - I have attached 2 images which describe the problem best..

Pleas any advice - I thank you in advance.

[image]
[image]

This error was two things - thank you everybody for your help.
1) add namespace to DB file

```
namespace C_Classes
```

{
    using System;
    ...

```
public class DB
```

2) Change Target Framework in the Project Properties and change it to ".Net Framework 4" from "...Client Profile"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you've added a Project reference to the C_Classes project?

Otherwise I've seen these types of issues when the project is set to target ".Net Framework 4 Client Profile" (which it sometimes sets as the default).

Check your Target Framework in the Project Properties and change it to ".Net Framework 4".

Comment: Target Framework in the Project Properties and change it to ".Net Framework 4" - This was as it was before - good advice thought I appreciate your help.

Shall I upload the project?

Comment: Wait i was wrong - I chanegd it - Fixed

THANK YOU ALL A BIG THANK YOU :D :D :D
THANK YOU ALL A BIG THANK YOU :D :D :D
THANK YOU ALL A BIG THANK YOU :D :D :D
THANK YOU ALL A BIG THANK YOU :D :D :D

Answer (score 2):

Your snippet of (presumably) DB.cs doesn't show a namespace declaration - so the `DB` class is just in the global namespace. If you want it in the C_Classes namespace you'll need:

```
namespace C_Classes
{
    public class DB
    {
        // etc
    }
}
```

Unlike VB, a C# class doesn't end up in a namespace without a namespace declaration appearing in the source code.

Comment: Ok adding this made the red underlines go - however the top image at the top  one now changes to blue..
using C_Classes;  << blue underline

Comment: @Gopher: It's not clear what you mean by "the top image at the top one now changes to blue" - is there a compiler error? If so, tell us what that is instead of just using pictures. My guess is that it's just saying the using directive isn't needed, because you're fully qualifying the references to `C_Classes.DB`. Just use `DB` in your code instead of `C_Classes.DB` so that the using directive is actually useful.

Comment: Ok - sorry - one error remains
The declaration at the top "using C_Classes"

The type or namespace name 'C_Classes' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Gopher2011: So do you have a reference from your main project to the C_Classes project? As a side-note, I would *seriously* recommend that you try some simple console apps before going much further. There's no much point in diving into databases and GUIs while you're unsure of the fundamentals of the language. When you run into a problem, you won't know whether it's due to C#, GUIs, threads, databases etc.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't see a namespace enclosing your `DB` class.

Enclose your `DB` class as shown below:

```
namespace C_Classes
{
    using System;
    ...

    public class DB
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: namespace C_Classes
{

    using System;
    ...

    public class DB
    {

    }

Comment: Precisely. You can have your using statements inside the namespace block or move outside it like in your Main class.

Answer (score 1):

Does the second project have a reference to the first one?  That isn't made clear in the images provided.  Expand the "References" folder in the second project and see if there's a reference to the first project there.  If there isn't, just right-click on the "References" folder and add a Project Reference to it.

The second thing I notice is that there's no explicit namespace in the `DB` file.  I'm not 100% sure if there's an implicit one when it's compiled in an assembly, but I wouldn't count on it.  Try wrapping that class in an explicit `C_Classes` namespace and see if that helps.

Comment: The solution has a start-up project C0001 - Use C_Classes and its project dependency's are set to C_Classes. I am unsure if they should be anywhere else.

Comment: @Gopher2011: I'm not sure what you're doing in the internals of your projects by that description.  The application context should be the startup project, yes.  However, it will need a reference to any other projects (or other resources) it needs.  Right-click on the References folder in the application project and add a reference.  The easiest way to add one for another project in the same solution is to add it as a Project Reference.